# Customize top bar ubuntu 18.04 gnome 3

Tags: gnome, 18.04, top-bar

I try to remove parts of the top bar in Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3. First I have removed the whole top bar with a part of CSS because we didn't used it at all, but we have installed the TopIcons plugin for our notifications because our software work with that plugin. Removing the complete bar don't work anymore, because also the TopIcons are not visible then. I still like to remove the right top corner part of this bar, as we made our own "Shutdown and Restart" buttons in the menu. The reason is to avoid users using the settings panel and make it impossible to use the "wired settings".

I would like to remove this:

[image: Top bar]

Is there any way to customize this bar or a way to remove parts of the top bar? I have used this CSS to remove the complete top bar, that was working well:

```
echo "#panel { height: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px; } #panel .popup-menu-arrow, #panel .system-status-icon { color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }" >> /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

Comment: Using some sort of permissions to disable those buttons seems more secure (and better practice overall), though I don't know whether it's possible.

Comment: I've already tried to find settings to disable them, but it doesn't seem to exist. Removing the settings panel completely doesn't seem to work either, it breaks other functionality.

Comment: I don't get the "*The reason is to avoid users using the settings panel*..." part. How's disabling that part of the top bar would help to achieve your goal? Even if you disable that part of the top bar there are other ways to launch *Settings* (e.g. from "Activities" overview, running `gnome-control-center` command).

Comment: Yes you are right, but I can't find any way to remove the gnome-control-center in general. You can uninstall it, but it breaks other functionality. Removing / disabling the gnome-control-center in some way would be the best, but beside that I still like to remove that part in my top bar.